# How can I save a pysimplegui chart as a pdf

Tags: pdf, save, pysimplegui

I made a graph using Pysimplegui, but I want to print it out as a pdf.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Search the topics on google or stackoverflow for "tkinter canvas to pdf", `window['GRAPH'].widget` is the tk.canvas.